# <a> tag in another <a> tag

Tags: html, css

I have a strange problem with my html/css code. I would like to have a  tag in another one  tag. Here is a basic code of my task:

```
<a href='2.html'>
  <div style="width: 300px; height: 200px; padding-left: 100px; padding-top: 100px;">
    text <a href='1111.html'> OK </a> text
  </div>
</a>
```

This solution doesn't help me because of the task and the current code of the application:

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 200px; padding-left: 100px; padding-top: 100px;">
  <a href='2.html'>text </a><a href='1111.html'> OK</a> <a href='2.html'>text </a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Whats your goal actually?
What do you want to achieve?

Comment: It's invalid HTML so you should find another way.

Comment: You can't have a link inside another link. The browser won't know what to do with it.

Comment: So what is it that does/doesn't happen that you don't/do want to happen when use the above code snippets?

Comment: Then which link address will the browser redirect to?

Comment: If you add '</a>' after okay in your second code snippet it would be valid html. But is this what you want to achieve? Do you want the first text to be a link to page A, "OK" a link to page B, and the text after a link to page C?

Comment: it's Invalid HTML code, you cannot have a hyperlink inside another hyperlink.explain more about you need.Why you putting hyperlink inside another hyperlink

Answer (score 6):

> I would like to have a tag in another one tag.

You cannot. It is forbidden by the HTML specification.

---

[HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element):

> Content model:
>      Transparent, but there must be no interactive content descendant.

`a` elements are interactive content.

---

[HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2):

> ```
> <!ELEMENT A - - (%inline;)* -(A)       -- anchor -->
> ```

Note the `-(A)` which excludes a element descendants.

---

[XHTML 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions):

> a
>       must not contain other a elements.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for isn't valid. Nested `<a>` tags are not allowed.
But you may try something like this

```
<div onclick="window.location='http://www.example.com/a.html'">
    text...
    <a href='http://www.example.com/b.html'>OK</a>
</div>
```

Comment: should add that nested `<a>`tags are allowed in HTML5 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: Where you read that it's allowed? I did a test with the w3c validator and it's not passing nested `<a>` tags.

Comment: oh my fault, I messed something up. What I wanted to say is that since HTML5 the a tag is allowed to contain block elements (or "flow content", I still prefer block content). But of course not other a tags, that wouldn't even make sense.

Answer (score 0):

That is invalid, you cannot have a hyperlink inside another hyperlink.

The only way of getting around, is to create a hyperlink1, then create hyperlink2, then again write a hyperlink 2 to make it feel like the hyperlink1 is a wrapper around hyperlink2. Which you're already using.

Answer (score 0):

in html language there is some rules that only one hyperlink inside the  tag. There is no rule that allow you to  insert two links in  tag.

```
<a href="YOUR LINK">OK</a>
```

This is the syntax that you should use. If you want it to give another link then you have to write the link another time.

Answer (score 0):

As people have previously stated, your code is invalid. `<a href='2.html'>text </a>` would just turn out as a link to 2.html but when you write `<a href='1111.html'> OK <a href='2.html'>text </a>` , you are trying to write a link which goes to 2.html and 1111.html at the same time. If you want the link to open two locations at the same time, you are going to have to use JavaScript. To do exactly what you want above, you'd want this:

HTML

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 200px; padding-left: 100px; padding-top: 100px;">
  <a href='2.html'>text </a><a href='javascript:openTwo();'> OK </a><a href='2.html'>text </a> 
</div>
```

JS

```
    function openTwo(){
      window.open("1111.html", "first Window", _blank);
      window.open("2.html", "second Window", _blank);
    }
```